# How to create a smoothing photo effect in GIMP

Tags: gimp, effects

How can I create a smoothing effect like this?:

[image]

It's clearer in his hairs and face.

Comment: Look through the painting style plugins. It's basically blurring or smudging but likely done via a plugin.

Comment: Is there any such plugin / script-fu ?

Comment: This seems to be done with Oil Painting Effect in Photoshop With Pixel Bender. Is there a way to do this in GIMP.[link](http://www.photoshoproadmap.com/Photoshop-blog/beautiful-oil-painting-effect-in-photoshop-with-pixel-bender/)

Comment: If you google "GIMP Oil Painting" there are several results, a few of which mention plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Got it :) its done with G'MIC plugin for GIMP .

> **'G'MIC => Enhancement => (Anisotropic) Smoothing'**

This  filter could do a similar job with several iterations, a big tensor and gradient smoothness and big amplitude.